# Printing a string in reverse with recursion

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, c-strings, function-definition

I printed a string in reverse with a loop which was pretty easy, but I thought of optimizing my code by making it neater and shorter. So, after my research on the best way, I found this recursion stuff which is a perfect substitute for loops/iterations. I am new to it but I still get some aspects about it. I got a code on github that suits my task but I don't uderstand it. Here is the code:

```
#include "main.h"


/**
 * _print_rev_recursion - prints string in reverse
 * @s: pointer to the string
 * Return: void
 */

void _print_rev_recursion(char *s)
{
if (*s > '\0')
{
    _print_rev_recursion(s + 1);
    _putchar(*s);
}

}
```

The code above prints a string in reverse, _putchar is a custom built replica of putchar(basically does the same thing).
What I am requesting for is an explanation of how the code works. Thanks!

Comment: What don't you understand about it? It's very simple recursion. To print a non-empty string in reverse, print all but the first character in reverse, then print the first character.

Comment: This is a GREAT application of using a Debugger and stepping into the recursive calls, looking at the call stack, ESPECIALLY once you dump the FIRST character via _putchar (the light bulb will come on then).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared at least like

```
void _print_rev_recursion( const char *s);
```

because  the passed string is not being changed within the function.

And the if statement should look like

```
if (*s != '\0')
```

This code snippet

```
if (*s > '\0')
{
    _print_rev_recursion(s + 1);
    _putchar(*s);
}
```

means that the function calls itself until the end of the string is encountered.

```
    _print_rev_recursion(s + 1);
```

The expression `s + 1` traverses the string to its end.

Then this statement

```
_putchar(*s);
```

in each function call outputs the current symbol starting from the end of the string in the reverse order.

For example if the passed string is `"Hello"` then the function calls itself step by step like

```
"Hello" - the first call
"ello" - the second call due to s + 1
"llo"  - the third call again due to s + 1 and so on
"lo"
"o"
```

And the characters outputted in the reverse order in each return from inner recursive call of the function.

```
'o'
'l'
'l'
'e'
'H'
```

Comment: Please can you create a flowchart to ease the understanding? I truly appreciate you assisting me